# Environment Variable in Dispatcher : 404

Tags: environment-variables, aem

I am trying to configure my dispatcher.any file in which i configured my publish port to pass via env. variables as below :

```
/renders
      {
      /rend01
        {
        # Hostname or IP of the render
        /hostname "127.0.0.1"
        # Port of the render
        /port "${Publish_IP}"
        # Connect timeout in milliseconds, 0 to wait indefinitely
        # /timeout "0"
        }
      }
```

When i check this via echo, it shows me below output

```
user@user-Aspire-5755:/etc$ echo ${Publish_IP}
 8589
```

This is port of my publish. In case if i put /port 8589 in dispatcher.any It works fine.But giving 404 in case i use env. variables. Not able to understand why its not picking up env. variable. My dispatcher version is 4.1

Below is the error log, i have made some changes, below is the latest one. Now i am using it for hostname that is localhost:

```
[Thu Feb 05 18:15:41 2015] [W] [16301(140595054811008)] /etc/apache2/conf/dispatcher.any:36: environment variable not defined: PUBLISH_IP
[Thu Feb 05 18:15:41 2015] [W] [16301(140595054811008)] Looking up host failed (): No address associated with hostname; entry ignored.
[Thu Feb 05 18:15:41 2015] [E] [16301(140595054811008)] No correct backend found in farm website
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hey thought I'd respond just in case anyone else is having this issue. In Centos/RedHat add your environment variables in:

```
/etc/sysconfig/httpd
```

Then restart apache:

```
sudo service httpd restart
```

Works fine.